# Only render html and css for specific stylesheet

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking to build out a web based brand guide for a brand. I have a template that runs  Bootstrap for the brand guide. The brand also uses Bootstrap as their main style guide but they have highly customized it. I'm trying to figure a way that the styles don't override eachother... without using an iframe and building two separate sites.

Is there a way to say, any content within this `<div class="brandstyles">` use x.css. Any content outside of the `<div>` **without having to add a class to every styles targeting the .brandstyle** that is the kicker. I also need it to render on ie8 as well (secondary kicker)

Ex:

```
<div class="adminstyle">

<header>
Global stylesheet only rendering y.css
</header>

<div class="brandstyles">
content for my clients style sheet targeting x.css
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: They customized the bootstrap.css file itself?  That's a no-no.

Comment: css is available to all the elements in the document. You can't isolate it, not even if you load the css with jQuery. Not even if the content was loaded with ajax. You have to prefix.

Comment: If they have customised the bootstrap.css file directly then it's going to cause you issues, but you could take each of the css files and insert .adminstyle and .brandstyles receptively at the beginning of every selector, it may work.

Comment: The answer is no - physical stylesheets are loaded wholly and applied to the document - there is no way to use an entire CSS file itself as a selector. The only way to have an element that loads and uses different stylesheets that I can think of is to use an `iframe`, but it's unlikely to be the right solution for whatever you're doing.

Comment: Are there any Jquery or iframe options? The goal would be to not modify either of the site CSS so if anything changes on the production site, it would pickup the style changes automatically. The only side effect I see with iframe would have to be adjusted per frame.